# Can't call script more than once

Tags: vbscript, sap-gui

I need to update several Excel workbooks via BEx Analyzer. I have a main script which calls scripts A and B.

Script A will fill out the SAP logon window that pops up every time data is refreshed inside the workbook.
Script B will enter the required date.

The problem I keep encountering is that the code works perfectly for the first workbook. Once the `ExcelFileRefresh` function is called for the second (third, fourth, etc.) workbook, script A starts to fail. It will not activate the SAP Logon window, but instead send the keystrokes to another window, namely the folder containing the main script.

Strangely, if I then run script A manually by double clicking on it, it will work fine, and script B will do it's thing... Unfortunately I cant figure it out on my own.

List of unsuccessful attempts to fix this issue:

- I tried setting `WScript.Sleep` pauses.
- I tried setting `SuccessSAPLogon` to `Nothing` at the end of script A.
- I tried activating the Excel workbook before calling script A.
- I tried fusing script A and B into one file.

**Main script**

```
Filepath1 = "X:\ExcelBook1.xlsm"
Filepath2 = "X:\ExcelBook2.xlsm"

ExcelFileRefresh(Filepath1)
ExcelFileRefresh(Filepath2)

Function ExcelFileRefresh(Var)
    Set Excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    Excel.Visible = True
    Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\SAP Shared\BW\BExAnalyzer.xla")
    Excel.Run ("BExAnalyzer.xla!SetStart")
    Set Connection = Excel.Run("BExAnalyzer.xla!sapBEXgetConnection")
    Excel.Run("BExAnalyzer.xla!sapBEXinitConnection")
    Set ExcelBook = Excel.Workbooks.Open(Var, 0, False)

    '--- Initiate Scripts ---'

    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    objShell.Run "ScriptA.vbs"
    objShell.Run "ScriptB.vbs"

    Excel.Application.Run ("MenuRefreshVariables")
    Excel.Run "CommandButton1"
    Excel.Run "retreiveData"
    ExcelBook.Save
    Excel.Quit

    Set ExcelBook = Nothing
    Set Excel = Nothing
    Set objShell = Nothing
End Function
```

**ScriptA**

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

SuccessSAPLogon = False
Do While SuccessSAPLogon = False
    SuccessSAPLogon = objShell.AppActivate("SAP Logon")
Loop

objShell.SendKeys "{TAB 4}"
objShell.SendKeys "{RIGHT}"
objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
objShell.SendKeys "myWarehouse"
objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
objShell.SendKeys "BW"
objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER 2}"
```

**ScriptB**

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

SuccessVariables = False
Do While SuccessVariables = False
    SuccessVariables = objShell.AppActivate("Select Values")
Loop

objShell.SendKeys "{TAB 3}"
objShell.SendKeys "{DOWN}"
objShell.SendKeys "{TAB 14}"
DateA = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), Day(Date)-3)
objShell.SendKeys DateA
objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```